# Existence of linear continuous functional on locally convex TVS

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Let $c>1$ and $X$ be a locally convex TVS. Take $a,b\in X$ and a closed subspace $Y$ of $X$ such that $Y\cap \{(1-t)a+bt \ | \ t\in\mathbb{R}\}=\emptyset$. How to prove that there exist $f\in X'$ such that $\mathrm{min}\{f(a),f(b)\}=c$ and $f(y)=0$ for every $y\in Y$ ?

Comment: Which forms of the Hahn-Banach theorem(s) do you know?

Comment: For real vector spaces, normed (real and complex) spaces and for local convex spaces. Probably I should use Hahn-Banach separation theorem, but now I don't see how exactly it should be done. I don't see why the assumption $c>1$ is important. I tried do this and I used only fact that $c>0$.

Comment: Right, you need one of the separation variants. Indeed $c > 1$ is irrelevant, $c > 0$ suffices (you can also take $c < 0$). By the way, we only need $Y \cap \{ (1-t)a + tb \mid t\in [0,1]\} = \varnothing$, no need to look at the whole affine line.

Comment: @DanielFischer, now I see that my proof doesn't work. Separation theorem give us function for which $f(x)<f(y), \ x\in \{(1-t)a+bt|t\in \mathbb{R}\}, \ y\in Y$, but we need $f(y)=0$ for every $y\in Y$. We cannot control values of $f$ in this way.

Comment: $f(Y)$ is a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}$. If $f(a) < f(y)$ for every $y\in Y$, which linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ can $f(Y)$ be?

Comment: Oh, right... It was obvious.